# Update script in one location among many desktop

Tags: scripts, updates, remote-desktop, automatic

My friend have to update 60 Ubuntu desktops and also put script in one location. They need to update with any automated tool or script. How do they do it?

Comment: Do all these servers could be connected through ssh without password asking as described here: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html ? What are names of your servers? Do you want to parse a file with their names or what? Do all these servers allow root login? Do all these servers have the admin user with the same username and password? Do they configured orchestration?